# Selected data not shown in HTML table

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

Why is my code not working? I tried to `{{row[0]}}` and it works. But this is not useful when I add DELETE / UPDATE buttons to `Row-[0]` instead of `ID` in `@app.route`.

```
@app.route("/register_style")   
def style_list():
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    SQLPATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'DatBaseTexCO.db' )
    conn = db.connect(SQLPATH)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    Query = ("SELECT style_ID,styleNo,styleName,styleYarn,styleLabel,styleType FROM style_table")
    curs.execute(Query)    
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    print(rows)
    return render_template("newstyle.html", rows=rows)
```

HTML side (this does not show table jingja2 as `{{row['style_ID']}}`) :

```
<tbody>                
    {% for row in rows %}                                   
    <tr>
        <td>{{row['style_ID']}}</td>
        <td>{{row['styleNo']}}</td>
        <td>{{row['styleName']}}</td>
        <td>{{row['styleYarn']}}</td>
        <td>{{row['styleLabel']}}</td>
        <td>{{row['styleType']}}</td>             
    </tr>                       
    {% endfor %}             
</tbody>

<tr>
    <td> {{row[0]}} </td>
    <td> {{row[1]}} </td>
    <td> {{row[2]}} </td>
    <td> {{row[3]}} </td>
    <td> {{row[4]}} </td>
    <td> {{row[5]}} </td>
    <td> {{row[6]}} </td>
```

Comment: You set @app.route("/") twice this will shadow your second function. Remove this part here: 
```@app.route("/")
    def home():
       print(request.args)
       return render_template("styleprod.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few inconsistencies in your code with variables declared multiples times and other things. I would go through that once more.

However regarding your issue i see two clear syntax errors in your code.

1.

```py
rows = curs.fetchall
```

should be

```py
rows = curs.fetchall()
```

2. and this probably the one that is causing the issue you are looking at:

```
      <tr>
          <td>{{row[style_ID]}}</td>
          <td>{{row[styleNo]}}</td>
          <td>{{row[styleName]}}</td>
          <td>{{row[styleYarn]}}</td>
          <td>{{row[styleLabel]}}</td>
          <td>{{row[styleType]}}</td>
      </tr>
```

here you are missing the quotes around the key names. This here should work:

```
      <tr>
          <td>{{row['style_ID']}}</td>
          <td>{{row['styleNo']}}</td>
          <td>{{row['styleName']}}</td>
          <td>{{row['styleYarn']}}</td>
          <td>{{row['styleLabel']}}</td>
          <td>{{row['styleType']}}</td>             
      </tr>
```